# Active SC fiber connection not 'turning on' port

Tags: lan, fiber

Multimode LC connected to Catalyst 2950.  Other end of cable connected to Catalyst 2900 Series X 100baseFX connector.  When the two switches connect via fiber there seems to be no communication.  The link lights do not turn on.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  Could the ports be dirty?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try swapping the fibers on one end? You need the fiber to crossover between the switches.

Comment: No because they only fit in one way.  If I pull out the fiber connectors from the FX connector I can see one has a red light going through it.  That cable connects to the GBIC Transmit end on the 2950.  The cable set only fits in one way on the FX port.  It may be an SC connector, I'm not sure.

Comment: The fiber connector will pop out of the SC housing, and you can reverse them. The end-to-end requirement is that Fiber A on one end needs to connect to Fiber B on the other end. Tx must go to Rx.

Comment: If the 2950 uses LC connectors, then it's a 1000b-fx.  If the 2900 is really 100b-fx, there is a speed mismatch.

Comment: Thanks Ron Maupin, I will try reversing the fiber connector.

Comment: Ron Trunk:  Wouldn't autonegotiate just set the speed to 100b-fx if one side is limited to that speed?  A speed mismatch shouldn't prevent the connection from being made.

Comment: A speed mismatch will not work with fiber the way it does with copper. The different speed use different light wavelengths, so they have different receivers, and transmitters (laser, LED) which can only send at one wavelength.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2950's optical ports are gigabit -- 1000b-SX based on "multimode". That will not, *ever*, connect to a 100b-FX peer. They are different speeds, and different signalling protocols.

If your 2950 has SFP ports, you *might* be able to find a compatible 100bFX module for it.

Comment: My old 2950 has 2 GBIC ports.

Comment: Exact model # of the switches? (very old 2950C's had FX ports) I am unaware of anyone still making GBIC FX modules. (SFP's, sure, but not full sized GBIC)